# Calling a Dialog from a Dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am trying to complete my login dialog in my application and I have problems with handling my dialogs.

I have three dialogs, first an AlertDialog as a login dialog, second a progressDialog and an  alertDialog which displays an error message. Here is my code:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case KBConstants.DIALOG_LOGIN_ID:
        TextView textUsername;
        TextView textPassword;
        TextView textSave;
        // Here I build my Layout
        ...
        // return dialog
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(R.string.login_title).setMessage(R.string.login_introduction).setView(loginLayout).setIcon(R.drawable.kreative_barometer_72x72)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.login_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        final DialogInterface d = dialog;
                        if (checkBoxSave.isChecked()) {
                            setRememberLogin(true);
                        } else {
                            setRememberLogin(false);
                        }
                        waitConnect = ProgressDialog.show(KreativBarometerMainView.this, getString(R.string.login_connect_title), getString(R.string.login_connect_introduction), false, true);
                        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
                            public void run() {
                                Looper.prepare();
                                DataStruct dataStruct = null;
                                try {
                                    dataStruct = SoapHandler.makeCall(SoapHashMap.CHECK_USER_LOGIN, mainService.getSoapMap(), editUsername.getText().toString(), editPassword.getText().toString(), null, null);
                                    ServerMessageStruct sms = (ServerMessageStruct) dataStruct;
                                    if (sms.getMsgType() == 1) {
                                        mainService.setUserValidation(true);
                                        setLogin(editUsername.getText().toString(), editPassword.getText().toString());
                                    } else {
                                        mainService.setUserValidation(false);

                                        setLogin(null, null);
                                                                                }
                                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                                    mainService.setUserValidation(false);
                                    setLogin(null, null);

                                } catch(XmlPullParserException xmlppe){

                                } finally{
                                    if(!mainService.isUserValidated()){
                                        waitConnect.dismiss();
                                        showDialog(KBConstants.DIALOG_NO_LOGIN_USER_ID);
                                    }
                                }
                                waitConnect.dismiss();
                            }
                        };
                        t1.start();

                    }
                }).setNeutralButton(R.string.login_setup, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        /* User clicked setup so do some stuff */
                        startActivity(new Intent(packageContext, SettingView.class));
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton(R.string.login_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        /* User clicked cancel so do some stuff */
                        KreativBarometerMainView.this.finish();
                    }
                }).setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        KreativBarometerMainView.this.finish();

                    }
                }).create();
    case KBConstants.DIALOG_NO_LOGIN_USER_ID:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.login_info_error_user).setIcon(R.drawable.kreative_barometer_72x72).setTitle(R.string.login_error)
                .setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        showDialog(KBConstants.DIALOG_LOGIN_ID);
                    }
                }).create();
    }
    return null;
}
```

When a user clicks on "connect" (positive button) a SOAP call is made to consume a webservice which validates the user data. While the user is waiting for the call to be made, the progressDialog is shown to indicate the work. After the call has been made, the `DIALOG_NO_LOGIN_USER_ID` Dialog should be shown if the user data was not valid. The user can click on okay and the login dialog is shown again.

But the DIALOG_NO_LOGIN_USER_ID dialog is not showing. I tried to call the showDialog() after the Thread was started, but then there are threading issues. The dialog is shown, but the result of the validation is ignored.

Can anyone help me to understand how to manage the dialogs? Is there any other, perhaps "better" solution for using an AlertDialog as a login dialog?

regards,
htz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was making use of the class

`android.os.AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`

The best description is given in die JavaDoc:

"AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers."

By using the methods `onPreExecute()` you can manipulate View on the UI Thread.

After finishing this method, `doInBackground()` is invoked and here you can start your background operations. This method is not working on the UI Thread, so it is not blocking your application.

After this `onPostExecute()` is invoked and you can use your computeted results.

My problem was to correctly show a progress indicator while the background oeprations are made. This can be done by making use of the `onProgressUpdate()` method, which is working ob the UI Thread, while the background computations are made.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of you all you don't need to call a dialog inside another one. What you do is just  get the onClickListener to dialog buttons and do the things accordingly. e.g. When user clicks on your `"connect" (positive button)` you'll call the next dialog in the `onClick()` method.

But still, if you want it that way only, then you need an `Activity Context` which you can pass as a parameter to you custom dialog and call a new dialog using that context.

Comment: But this is what I am doing... I call the next second Dialog in the onClick() method of the first Dialog. I create the first dialog and in the onClick() a thread is started. At the end of this thread, the next dialog should be shown. While the thread is working, a progressdialog should be shown.

Can you explain the context thing? It is not clear to me why I need a special context for getting this to work. I am already using the `activity context` by calling `this`

Comment: You must google for `context`. And if you don't want it in `onClick` and want it only when the dialog is dismissed, then you can set `OnDismissListener` to your dialog.